# Dynamo Primary Partition Key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, partitioning

I have a dynamo table for a news page.

It consists of

guid,
newsDatetime, 
newsText,
language

What would be the best idea to structure the table?

Most users would see the first five text items ordered new newsDatetime.

You could switch the language, but every language has different news. Does it make sense to create entierly new dynamoDBs and switch the DB on language. (which will rarelly if ever happen)

The guid would be randomly distributed among paritions. But it would like to use the datetime as partition key, because of the ordering by datetime. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think your architecture is fine. To solve your need to filter by language, I'd suggest creating a new attribute concatenating `language` and `newsDatetime`.

Set your table to have the `guid` as partition-key and `newsDatetime` as sort-key. Then create a secondary index having the `guid` as partition-key and the concatenated attribute as the sort-key.

When you need to retrieve news regardless of language, scan the table in descending order using the sort-key. When you need to filter a language, use the secondary index scanning in descending order, but also using a `startswith="{language}"` filter condition.